# MVC default link in routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to set the homepage of asp.net mvc routing to follow:

default settings for home page link:
abc.com (accessible)
abc.com/Home(accessible)
abc.com/Home/Index(accessible)

new settings for home page link that I would like to achieve:
abc.com (not accessible) 
abc.com/Base (accessible) 
abc.com/Base/Index (not accessible)

How could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your index method with route attribute like this [Attribute Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)

```
[Route("/Base")]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    //your code here
}
```

I am suggesting this because its a special case of home page where you dont want to specify the action method, but in other controllers with lots of methods in it, you are gonna need the default route system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 Change Your `RouteConfig` Class under App_Start Folder

```
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using System.Web.Routing; 
namespace CMS 
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");    
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    } 
}

defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
```

Give your controller and action name here I have Home controller and action is Index.

Hope that helps.